# ThreeJS get uniform values for running material

Tags: three.js, webgl, shader

I added an object with a `MeshPhongMaterial` to my scene. I want to spy on the uniforms that Three is setting on the object. I thought it would be as simple as `obj.uniforms.uniformName`, but that doesn't actually exist. Is there a simple way to get the runtime uniforms [Three is setting](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/5c7e0df9b100ba40cdcaaf530196290e16c34858/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js#L4729)?

What I'm after is the uniform names and their values.

The method I came up with requires a double loop. The only thing I can see on a running material that's useful is `material.uniformsList` which is a list of `WebGLUniformLocation`s and values, but no names. There is also `material.program.uniforms` which is a key value store of names to `WebGLUniformLocation`s. It seems like you can zip the two together to get a uniform list, but is there a better way?

```
let builtUniforms = {};

// For every uniform in the array, look for its location in the program
// uniforms to get the name
for( x = 0; uniform = object.material.uniformsList[ x++ ]; ) {

    // uniform is [ { type, value }, WebGLUniformLocation ] but no name :(

    for( uniformName in object.material.program.uniforms ) {

        // If the WebGLUniformLocations match up, we've found the name
        if( object.material.program.uniforms[ uniformName ] === uniform[ 1 ] ) {

            builtUniforms[ uniformName ] = {
                value: uniform[ 0 ].value,
                name: uniformName
            };
            break;

        }
    }
}
```

1. Is there a more straightforward way to get the uniform names and values from a Three.Material?
2. Will the `uniformsList` or `program.uniforms` ever change? Do I need to build this object once per render loop, or can I build it once and resuse it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three stores the key value store you're looking for in `material.__webglShader.uniforms`

Also look in `THREE.UniformsLib`

and also `THREE.ShaderLib` - e.g. `THREE.ShaderLib.phong`

these contain the templates for built-in uniforms and also the shaders, like `MeshPhongMaterial`, which use them.

Comment: The std ones are built on the fly each time the shader is transmitted to WebGL. If you want detailed control, use a `ShaderMaterial` or even `RawShaderMaterial` -- an occasionally useful trick, to find out what attributes are being added by THREE.js, is to introduce an error in your shader. When WebGL barfs, halt the app and look at the error message in the Chrome console, which will contain the entire shader received by WebGL (your code plus THREE's additions).

Comment: That's what I'm doing in my question, but as you can see, the values three gives you are limited. it also does *not* have the regular uniforms passed in from three, it only has the webgl representations https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32257893/passing-an-array-of-vectors-to-a-shader-in-threejs

Comment: As I mentioned, it builds and manages a private list on the fly `material.__webglShader.uniforms` -- if you don't want THREE to step on your values, you'd probably be better off using RawShader and doing it yourself.

Comment: That's the answer to this question. I'm trying to spy on the three light shaders to copy light uniforms to other rawshadermaterials. three sets things like pointLightPosition magically on running shaders, and there's no way to access them. If I can't get the correct values to pass to a rawshadermaterial then the data isn't helpful to me